# How to combine batteries in series and parallel

Tags: batteries

I need to combine S*P number of batteries (same types) to get S times the voltage and P times the capacity. Which of the following combination is better? Is there any difference? [image]   _ [image]

Comment: As a theoretical exercise the cross-connections in A are unnecessary so I'd say B is better. However, as Andy aka's answer explains it is a bad idea to connect batteries in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

Don't connect batteries in parallel unless you wish to have trouble - if one battery fails it will discharge the one in parallel with it and likely damage that good battery and may even cause a fire or explosion depending on battery type.

Connect all the batteries in series and if the voltage you desire is not what the battery voltage gives use a buck converter to reduce the voltage to what you want. Buck converters of this type can be over 95% efficient at converting power to a different voltage level and they hardly take up any room and I bet you can get one off ebay for a really tiny fistful of dollars (The Clint Eastwood reference I apologize for LOL).

All is not sweetness and light even with them in series - over-load currents can cause cell reversal especially in NiCd cells but, this can also happen in parallel configurations.

Comment: uuuu eeee uuuu eeee uu, wah wahhh waaah +1

Comment: @gbulmer Nice to see the intellectual comment now and then, thanks LOL. Maybe that was a CE theme tune, now let me think - it reads like the good, the bad and the ugly?

Comment: As to parallel connections of batteries- you've got to ask yourself a question: "Do I feel lucky?"

Comment: Matched new cells can work in either config , but as aging increases chance of mismatch, any combination of S,P  passive balancing will increase aging of weakest cell more rapidly. Thats why active load balance is preferred. All my LiPo banks in series fail with 1 cell before the others which had useful life. Balance is the key to long life ( Yogi ) while the factories choose matching when making parallel /serial banks.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - wit abounds today

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f05hkd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In 10 years of experience with large battery banks, I have never seen that the cells are connected in parallel. I have always been connected in series.
That is, each element of the bank has enough current capacity, while achieving the required voltage, many cells are connected in series as needed.

Comment: Do you mean you use fig A?

Comment: @zud No. None of the proposed schemes. I edited my answer to include an explanatory schema. Each of the elements must be able to deliver the necessary current and then group through a serial connection the required amount of elements to achieve the required voltage.

Comment: All of these "battery banks" for sale everywhere to recharge your mobile phone are made up of parallel connections of lipos. So parallel is out there and common, but not in the Nixx chemistry.

Answer (score 0):

If they are Li-ion or Lipo cells then A is better because then you only need 3 balance circuits, whereas with B you need 9 balance circuits.

Whatever scheme you choose, you must match the capacities of all cells (or banks of parallel cells) in series. Cells which are connected in parallel do not have to be matched, because they always have equal voltage and so cannot go out of balance.